# When does an ndb Model's _post_put_hook have a future different from self?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Google App Engine's ndb provides a [`_post_put_hook(self, future)`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model__post_put_hook), documented as follows:

> Hook that runs after put()

To understand this hook better, I am wondering when `self` will differ from the result of the `future` argument.

The [Model Hooks](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#hooks) documentation provides:

> If you use post-hooks with asynchronous APIs, the hooks are triggered by calling check_result(), get_result() or yielding (inside a tasklet) an async method's future. Post hooks do not check whether the RPC was successful; the hook runs regardless of failure.
>
> All post- hooks have a Future argument at the end of the call signature. This Future object holds the result of the action. You can call get_result() on this Future to retrieve the result; you can be sure that get_result() won't block, since the Future is complete by the time the hook is called.

However, when I call `put` asynchronously like this:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class MyModel(ndb.Model):
   xyz = ndb.StringProperty()

   def _post_put_hook(self, future):
      print "self.xyz: {}, future.xyz: {}".format(
             self.xyz, future.get_result().get().xyz))

m = MyModel()
f = m.put_async()
f.wait()

m.xyz = 'abc'
f = m.put_async()
f.wait()
```

Outputs:

```
self.xyz: None, future.xyz: None
self.xyz: abc, future.xyz: abc
```

In the context of a 'put_async', I think one might reasonably expect the `self` to be the model before modification, and the `future` to be the model as now saved. Otherwise it is not clear what purpose `future` would have in the `put` context.

When would `self` and `future` be different in the context of a `put`? What is the purpose of the `future` here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the answer is in the description:

> Post hooks do not check whether the RPC was successful; **the hook
>   runs regardless of failure**.

The future can contain the reason for a failure when doing a `put()`. You can use this knowledge to handle when a put fails by using a hook. For instance, if your `_post_put_hook` was responsible for incrementing an associated SUM aggregation model based on properties of the model, it could first check to see if the `put` succeeded before trying to increment the associated SUM aggregation model. I do not believe the value of `self` and `future.get_result().get()` will ever be different, as long as the RPC did not fail.

There is always the possibility that another request updated the model after this request's `put` but before the `_post_put_hook` was executed, in which `future.get_result().get(use_cache=False)` may return a different value.