# Why is _post_put_hook not running inside a transaction?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have some code that queues up a task inside `_post_put_hook`. 
The task retrieves the key and fetches the entity. However sometimes the worker fails because the object for that key hasn't been created yet, but will succeed when it next runs.Note that we're retrieving the object by key, so I expect the data to be consistent.

**I'm only calling the enqueue on commit**, so I'd expect the object to be created by the time the task runs. In the sample below, I find that `_post_put_hook` is not in a transaction which seems to be the cause of the issue, but **why isn't it in a transaction?**

Here's a sample:

```py
    @ndb.synctasklet
    def log_usage(self):
       @ndb.transactional_tasklet(xg=True)
       def _txn():   
           yield Log.insert_document_log_async() 

       yield _txn()


    class Log(ndb.Expando):
        @classmethod
        @ndb.tasklet
        def insert_document_log_async(cls):
            log = cls()
            logging.debug("insert document log in transaction: {}".format(ndb.in_transaction()))
            yield log.put_async()

        @ndb.synctasklet
        def _post_put_hook(self, future):
            @ndb.synctasklet
            def _callback_on_commit():
                key = future.get_result()
                yield SqlTaskHelper.enqueue_syncronise_sql_model_async(key)

            logging.debug("_post_put_hook In transaction: {}".format(ndb.in_transaction()))
            ndb.get_context().call_on_commit(lambda: _callback_on_commit())
```

The code is executed as follows:

1. `log_usage` is called which calls `insert_document_log_async`
2. When calling `insert_document_log_async`, logging indicates that we're in a transaction (insert document log in transaction: True).
3. But the `_post_put_hook` logging indicates we're **not in a transaction** (so call_on_commit is executed immediately, which is what I suspect the issue is). The task runs shortly after and the entity isn't always available.

**I'd like to know why `_post_put_hook` is executing outside of a transaction.**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question was answered on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/Zx5LN3AVjUA). I'm re-posting from there:

"Note that post hooks do not check whether the RPC was successful. The hook runs regardless of failure that might have occurred due to issues, more specifically the [contention](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entity-models) which is when you attempt to write to a single entity group too quickly. Also note that it is normal that a small number of datastore operations will result in timeout in normal operation. Read more [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/handling_datastore_errors) about the most common datastore issues and [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/contention) how to avoid the contention.

In case you need any coding assistance, I suggest you post your inquiries on Stack Overflow where the community of developers are better prepared to assist you in that matter. Google Groups is oriented more towards general opinions, trends, and issues of general nature regarding Google Cloud Platform.

If an exception is detected by Datastore, it would be raised when the code calls [get_result()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/async#using), so the key would not return. However, note that “all post- hooks have a Future argument at the end of the call signature. This Future object holds the result of the action. You can call get_result on this Future to retrieve the result; you can be sure that get_result won't block, [since the Future is complete by the time the hook is called.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entity-models#using_model_hooks)”

That said, in case you don’t have an exception, the future already has the result and get_result function is not blocking, occasionally failing to retrieve the key. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733546/when-does-an-ndb-models-post-put-hook-have-a-future-different-from-self/15744244#15744244) Stack Overflow post with a suggestion to resolve an issue similar to your case."

Comment: No, I believe they're misunderstanding the problem. We are checking the value of get_result, we're not getting exceptions. The issue we are experiencing is that the value is being queued up before it's actually been committed. So when the task first runs, the value isn't available. On subsequent run, the value is available and succeeds.